# Javascript callback with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, settimeout

I am really new to funcitonal paradigm and I have a hard time understanding what is going on with the following snippet.

```
const countDown = (val, cb, delay = 1000) => {
  cb(val, delay);
  return (val > 0) ? setTimeout(() => countDown(val - 1, cb, delay), delay) : val;
}

countDown(5, console.log, 100)
```

Why the following doesn't work, given the fact that `setTimeout` takes a function as an argument?

```
const countDown = (val, cb, delay = 1000) => {
  cb(val, delay);
  return (val > 0) ? setTimeout(countDown(val - 1, cb, delay), delay) : val;
}

countDown(5, console.log, 100)
```

Comment: You're not passing it a function argument, you're passing it the result of `countDown`. That's why the arrow function exists on the first example.

Comment: `countDown` is a function, but `countDown(val - 1, cb, delay)` is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setTimeout` function takes a callback function as first argument. So in your example you need to pass a function definition and not the function call.

this is a function definition:
`() => countDown(val - 1, cb, delay), delay)`

or the same without arrow functions:
`function() { countDown(val - 1, cb, delay), delay) }`

while this is a function call:
`countDown(val - 1, cb, delay)`

Answer (score 0):

This is another way you can look at your problem. `countDown` is concerned with repeatedly calling a function, decrementing a counter, and inserting some time in between the function calls – that's a *lot* for one function.

I'll be abstracting some of this complexity away with `delay` and `effect` and `repeat`. You'll notice that `countDown` requires *zero* logic once we've abstracted to this point – this is sometimes why people say functional programs can take on a declarative resemblance.

```js
const delay = ms => x =>
  new Promise (r => setTimeout (r, ms, x))

const effect = f => x =>
  (f (x), x)
  
const repeat = n => f => x =>
  n === 0 ? x : repeat (n - 1) (f) (f (x))
  
const countDown = (x, ms, f) =>
  repeat (x)
         (p => p.then (effect (f)) .then (delay (ms)) .then (x => x - 1))
         (Promise.resolve (x))
  
countDown (5, 1000, console.log)
  .then (x => console.log ('done', x))
```